# Add form input to array with javascript using unshift()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add elements to an array via a form. I am using the unshift() method. The code below doesn't work and I would like to know why.

```
<form>
<input id="input"> </input>
<input type = "button" id="button"> Click me </input>
</form>


<script>

var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var myArray = [];
myArray.unshift(input);



button.onclick = function alerted (){
alert(myArray);
};


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoted code runs *immediately* when the page is loaded. The form field won't have anything in it then, so its value will be `''`. When you alert that, the default `toString` operation on the array will result in `''` and the alert will be blank.

You want to run your `unshift` code in response to a user event, such as the button being clicked, rather than right away. You can do that by setting `input` to be the element (remove `.value` from that line) and then moving your line with `unshift` into the function you're assigning to `onclick`, adding the `.value` there:

```
button.onclick = function alerted (){
    myArray.unshift(input.value);
    alert(myArray);
};
```

Other notes:

1. You never write `</input>`. Normally you don't close `input` tags at all. If you're writing XHTML (you probably aren't), you'd put the `/` within the main `input` tag like this: `<input id="input" />`. But again, you're probably not writing XHTML, just HTML.
2. The value (caption) of an `input` button goes in its `value` attribute, not content within opening and closing tags. (You would use opening and closing tags with the `button` element, not `input`.)

Taking all of that together, here's a minimalist update: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/otucad/1) | [source](http://jsbin.com/otucad/1/edit)

```
<form>
<input id="input"><!-- No ending tag -->
<input type = "button" id="button" value="Click me"><!-- No ending tag, move value where it should be -->
</form>
<script>

var input = document.getElementById("input"); // No .value here
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var myArray = [];

button.onclick = function alerted (){
    myArray.unshift(input.value); // Moved this line, added the .value
    alert(myArray);
};
</script>
```

Comment: How do I remedy this ? I should have asked that in the original question too

Comment: @Taoist: See the second paragraph (I don't recall -- amazingly -- whether I added that after posting the answer).

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/MLSVB/)

You need to a) get the value in the click and b) return false if you want the button to not submit. I changed to button. Alternative is `<input type="button" value="click me" id="button" />`

You may even want to empty and focus the field on click...

```
<form>
<input id="input" type="text"/>
<button id="button"> Click me </button>
</form>


<script>

var input = document.getElementById("input"); // save the object
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var myArray = [];




button.onclick = function alerted (){
    myArray.unshift(input.value); // get the value
    alert(myArray);
    return false;
};


</script>​
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the new value in the onclick function.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/SeqWN/4/

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var i = document.getElementById("input");
var myArray = [];

button.onclick = function alerted (){
  myArray.unshift(i.value);
  alert(myArray);
};​
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: He was getting the value of the input outside of the function. Whatever you want to call that.

Comment: Justin, input is accessible in that anonymous function even if it's not defined within it. `var test = 'test'; (function somefunction(){ console.log( test ) })();`

Comment: @azuz, I'm not sure I follow your point? Are you suggesting something be changed?

Comment: @aziz.punjani: Yes, but I think Justin's point is that by taking the value from the input's `.value` prior to the click event, it's going to be blank, because there's no value in the input yet. Justin's changed it so that the code takes the value of `.value` when the click occurs, after the user has had time to type something in.

Comment: Justin that's a slightly inefficient way to do it because you grab the dom element EACH time the button is clicked. You should only need to grab the dom element once and store a reference to it then just get the value from that referenced element.

Comment: @TJ My point was it's not a scoping issue just like you already stated.